# How to select nodes that are behind each other?

Tags: inkscape, path

I want to connect two nodes which are already at the same spot:

[image: image description]
Here you can see it's actually 2 nodes:

[image: image description]

I need to select them both as they are (atop of each other) and join them. This is the desired result:

[image: image description]

Comment: I'm not an inkscape user but can't you just drag the mouse from outside and then over the points to make a selection? What have you tried?

Comment: No I can't, that does not do anything at all. I tried all kinds of stuff and I actually once managed to do this by accident. If you're not an Inskcape user I don't think you will find an answer because I am an inscape user and I've really tried to figure it out.

Comment: @Luciano: Actually, you are correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two easy ways:

1. Drag a selection rectangle over the position.
2. Make use of the fact that Inkscape preserves selection when you undo or redo actions: Move one node away, select both nodes and then *undo.*

For some reason, if you select two nodes at the same position, they are not rendered anymore. Nonetheless, if you hit *join selected nodes,* you get the desired result.

Comment: Ah well, the fact that the selected nodes are not selected kinda confused me. Also made me wonder what's the purpose of rectangular selection.

Comment: Rectangular selection is the standard for most graphic softwares, and in the same situation in Illustrator (for example) you wouldn't be able to tell how many points are selected.

Comment: Eeekk...maye thios would deserve a feature request, if there is not any, for a shortcut on these situations?